# Getting text of dynamically added MenuItem

Tags: c#, menustrip

I have a function which adds Labels to a MenuStrip. On the ItemClicked function, I was using the following code:

```
MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
string a = mi.Text;
```

However, I get the following error, upon reading this:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: That means casting to `MenuItem` wasn't possible.

Comment: Then how should I go about getting the text?

Comment: I should extend my first comment with: 'what means that `sender` is not `MenuItem`'. You have to find out what `sender` really is first.

Comment: Ah I see. It's a MenuStrip, but after casting as a Menustrip, I'm unsure as to how I should get the text from it.

Comment: Can you post your code? Where are you checking for the text?

Comment: Just casting sender to MenuStrip:

   MenuStrip a = sender as MenuStrip;

Comment: But what is the name of method and when is called? We need to see more code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4r6N23jr - populateMenu(); is called on Form1_Load()

Comment: Edited my answer. I tried it works.

Comment: Thanks, I realize this was a ridiculous mistake now -_-

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {

         string str=e.ClickedItem.Text;
        }
```